# "jasmine is not defined"

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I recently updated my Jest version from 24.x to 27.0.0 and this broke one of the tests I had:

I had my test framework set up as this:

```
describe('PersonDescriber', () => {
  let service: PersonDescriber;

  const mock = {
    getAutocompleteResults: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({features: [{relevance: 1, meta: {}},{relevance: 0}]}),
  };
}
```

As soon as I updated versions it is now erroring out for `jasmine` saying:

`ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined`

Any idea what is going on? Do I manually need to import `jasmine`? When I was on the old version of Jest, I did not have an import for jasmine in this file.

jest:

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.ts",
      "!**/*.dto.ts",
      "!**/*.model.ts",
      "!**/*.module.ts",
      "!**/main.ts",
      "!**/configuration.ts"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@config/(.*)": "<rootDir>/config/$1",
      "@personDescriber/(.*)": "<rootDir>/personDescriber/$1",
      "@health/(.*)": "<rootDir>/health/$1",
      "@shared/(.*)": "<rootDir>/shared/$1"
    },
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 20,
        "functions": 20,
        "lines": 20,
        "statements": 20
      }
    },
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
```

Comment: Do you use `jasmine` in other files?

Comment: I do not. It is only in this one test file @ThomasSablik

Comment: What `testRunner` is set in your `jest` config? It would help if you post your `package.json` and `jest` config.

Comment: I think they've changed the default test runner. In the previous version it was `jasmine2`. Now it's `jest-circus/runner`. You could set `testRunner` to `jasmine2` or rewrite the tests.

Comment: Just updated with what the jest config is in package.json

Comment: You can see it in the docs: https://archive.jestjs.io/docs/en/24.x/configuration#testrunner-string and https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testrunner-string. The default in 24.x is `jasmine2` and the default in 27.x is `jest-circus/runner`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default test runner was changed from `jasmine2` in version 24.x to `jest-circus/runner` in version 27.x. You can either manually set the runner back to `jasmine2` or rewrite your tests to `jest-circus` style. The configuration key is `testRunner`. You can find more information in

[Jest docs 24.x](https://archive.jestjs.io/docs/en/24.x/configuration#testrunner-string)

[Jest docs 27.x](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testrunner-string)

[`jest-circus`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/jest-circus)

Answer (score 3):

Check your imports. Prolly you have missed '/jest'
I had similar problem because I have imported those elements from '@ngneat/spectator' instead of '@ngneat/spectator/jest'.

Correct imports:

```
import {
    createComponentFactory,
    mockProvider,
    Spectator,
    SpectatorFactory,
} from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';
```